# Stovetop Waffle Iron vs Electric Waffle Maker

Tags: waffle

I can't decide between buying a [waffle maker (electric appliances used to cook waffles simply by pouring in the batter and turning the device on), or waffle iron (cast iron devices used to cook waffles over a fire or over your stove top)](http://easykitchenappliances.com/waffle-maker-or-waffle-iron-whats-the-difference/). This link presents convincing arguments and counterarguments. I assume no significant price differences.

Have I overlooked anything beneath? Can someone please counsel which to buy?

#### Waffle Iron

1. Easier to clean.
2. Can control temperature.
3. Can save space by being stored away.
4. Longer lifetime.  The Waffle Maker will stop working after 5-10 years.

   #### Waffle Maker
5. Requires less human control and skill, and so better for amateur?
6. Simultaneous; more exact, uniform heating on both sides.

Comment: A waffle maker can also be easier to clean (several models have removable plates), have temperature control, and be stored away.  Maybe there are other variables.

Comment: A basic google search for "waffle irons" turns up, almost exclusively, "waffle makers" with the few exceptions being 'decorative' items. Today "waffle irons" is a term used practically interchangeably with "waffle maker". Only looking at the article you link to does the meaning of your question become clear.

Comment: Seconding @moscafj 's opinion on temperature control. It is the most important variable imo, because you get precision as to when to fill the plates and when to remove.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used both but haven't used a waffle iron in the last 30 years even though I still own one. (OK: TBH: the waffle iron is hanging on the wall as decoration and a reminder to my grandmother)

There's just no substitute for a [real Belgian Waffle maker](https://www.amazon.de/Frifri-FI-W102A-Multex-600-Waffeleisen/dp/B007USIL9C) because the plates are interchangeable and you can make:

- [Brussels waffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Brussels_waffle.jpg)
- [Liège waffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gaufre_liege.jpg)
- [Waffle cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Waffle_cookies.jpg)
- [Fruit waffles](https://wereldsmaken.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/wafels-1-800x376.jpg)
- [Croque Monsieur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croque-monsieur)
- and so many more yummie Belgian things

whereas one waffle iron can only make one kind of waffles...

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert when it comes to waffles, but one thing that comes to mind is that a manual waffle iron may need to be flipped to deliver heat to both sides, whereas the electric one delivers more even heating by having hot plates on both sides.

You can buy a waffle maker (or 'snack maker', I think it's by Tefal) that does waffles, pancakes, mini doughnuts, wafers and even paninis, just swap the plates and you're good to go.

Comment: My neighbors have one that opens up so you can also use it as a griddle.  (I think it's a cuisinart griddler ... you can get sets, but the base model doesn't come with the waffle plates)